# Answering questions as a student.

Tags: discussion, answers, new-users

So I am new to the developer scene.  My knowledge is limited but I am very interested and have been studying hard for 5 months now.

One thing I have learned from my time in university and life in general, I learn by investigating and asking questions, which is why I'm drawn to this community.  Also, I believe that pushing myself to answer questions of others, really helps to refine my own understanding.  The problem is, I acknowledge that as I am a novice, I may steer others wrong with bad answers.

~Some say teaching something is how you achieve mastery. ~

The question is...

Do you encourage people to answer with limited experience?  Or should I leave the answering to the experts until I master an area?

Comment: If you know the answer, answer it. Even if you think some people may be able to answer it _better_ it could still be correct. If you don't think your answer is correct or don't want to post it, answering it for yourself that way you'll get better.

Comment: Thats true, you learn almost the same amount just answering it for yourself.  The only difference I guess is you don't get the feedback from the community.

Comment: I learned how to program mostly by answering questions on Stack Overflow, so yes, I'd say this is a good idea.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You definitely don't have to be an expert in a particular area, but you *should* be reasonably confident in your answer. If you're answering a good question which comes with a complete program demonstrating the problem, it's often pretty easy to be confident in the answer - because that answer contains a complete program which is effectively the code in the question, modified to work... and with an explanation, of course.

I answer questions where I'm "reasonably confident but not certain" but try to make that clear when I answer. (That's usually the case if I'm answering a question on a language I'm not familiar with, based just on the documentation.)

Your attitude to learning via problem-solving is an excellent one, and should be applauded :)

Comment: Differentially agree with the last sentance, also with the consideration they've given the site I think they'll be a great new user!

Comment: Alright, thanks.  

I need to just get a feel for my own knowledge base, and develop the "gut instinct" for how much I know, and how much I am BSing.

Comment: @DMrFrost: Rather than "gut instinct" I would try to develop ways of *validating* how much you know. That's a really valuable skill.

Comment: One note so - while it is mostly ok for Jon Skeet to never look for duplicates as his answers are always useful and unique (and he's [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) to start with :) ) it is not the case for anyone else. Please be relatively confident that questions you are answering are at least in some form unique and have not been answered 100+ times already.

Comment: And just in case the humour wasn't clear, it's *not* okay for me to not look for duplicates. I sometimes fail to when I should, and sometimes fail to find a dupe even when I try, but there's definitely no reason for me to get special treatment.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if you can add an answer, then go for it. You may from time to time get things wrong, but that will be indicated by votes and comments.

Just be patient and don't take negative comments and down votes to heart, see it as an opportunity to dig deeper in to what you could improve. You can always edit and improve answers.

Perhaps stick to topics that you are most familiar with to start with. I spent my early days on the site learning how the site works and what is expected by answering questions in tags that I was most familiar with.

Comment: Yes it is discouraging when you get downvoted to oblivion, but on a good day I just take it as a lesson and figure out where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in a similar boat: I'm a student with four years experience in various areas of computing, and I feel that I am in no way an expert. I mostly stick to the Python tag, sometimes branching out into JavaScript, because these are the areas I feel most comfortable in.

I will think about answering a question whenever I can. Sometimes it leads to me starting to type something out and then getting rid of it all, because maybe I didn't understand the problem as thoroughly as I thought or someone else has got an answer in just before me. Other times I'll come up with an answer that I think is very simple and straightforward, and someone will swipe the tick with a [single-line solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439954/check-if-something-in-a-dictionary-is-the-same-as-the-max-value-in-that-dictiona/44440305#44440305)<sup>1</sup>. That's going to happen all the time: be gracious and accept that yes, there are going to be people better than you, but you can still contribute to the discussion and help someone.

From my experience on SO, I quite commonly scroll down past the accepted and top voted answers just to see what else is available to me, and will quite often learn something - and whenever I do, I leave an upvote; I recommend you do the same! It encourages people like us who may feel like they're not making a difference to keep trying and work harder at giving quality answers.

I don't have a lot of accepted answers or rep but I'm getting there. And the best way to do better is to keep contributing, keep learning and keep my chin up. I hope that you do the same. :)

---

1. To be honest, when dealing with beginners I think it can often more useful to give a longer, more clear piece of code than a single-line solution with a more complicated concept involved. But at the end of the day the OP is going to pick which ever one helped them the most, so it's up to them.

Comment: I agree, as a beginner, usually I am not just look for one small piece that I missed, usually it is something more fundamental that I am lacking, and so I more thorough answer illuminates more.

Comment: @DMrFrost exactly - which is why I would usually lay something out with loops and comments over a lambda, for example. Not only because I feel that it's clearer for a beginner, but it's also a realm I'm more comfortable with. I couldn't really construct a tricky lambda on the fly, but I know what thought process I would apply to a problem, so I just show that whenever I can.

Comment: I suppose once you get good at this stuff, you can distinguish a high level member and assume they want an easy fix, and then you can see someone without the flair and give a lengthier explanation.  

As a user who may stumble across your javascript answers in the future... thanks for taking the time to type out longer explanations.